# Prevent WebView to open links in other browsers

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I have a webview and I wish that if `target=_blank`, then do not open it in the browser, but remains open in webview. 
I tried the code below:

```
private async void webView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
    {
        @"(function()
        {
            var hyperlinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for(var i = 0; i < hyperlinks.length; i++)
            {
                if(hyperlinks[i].getAttribute('target') != null)
                {
                    hyperlinks[i].setAttribute('target', '_self');
                }
            }
        })()"
    });
}
```

But there are some websites that can remain open in the webview and there is a website that opens in a browser. How do I fix this so that all links remain open on webview?

Comment: Could you share the html source you've used in `WebView`? As in my test, your code works well.

Comment: This is an example project for the above problem: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7T4TbqCaT741d1Ay  When already looking flight schedule and will choose the flight by pressing the select button, it will go directly to the web browser (not in webview), such as an image https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7UDItcmYCW-HCHZK (which I give a red circle). I want to stay in webview. How to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code didn't work because the "Select" button in your image is a HTML `<button>` element not a `<a>` element. When user click this button, it calls JavaScript functions to open in new window. So your code won't work for this scenario.

For handling the new window request, I'd suggest using [**WebView.NewWindowRequested** event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.newwindowrequested.aspx). This event occurs when a user performs an action in a [**WebView**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) that causes content to be opened in a new window. We can provide custom handling of the new window request and set the [**Handled**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewnewwindowrequestedeventargs.handled.aspx) property to true to prevent the default browser from being launched. Following is a simple sample:

```
private void webView_NewWindowRequested(WebView sender, WebViewNewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    webView.Navigate(args.Uri);

    args.Handled = true;
}
```

For more info, please see **Remarks** and **Examples** in [WebView.NewWindowRequested event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.newwindowrequested.aspx).

Comment: When using the code above, the link does not open in the web browser. But the link can not be opened. I want those links can remain open, but remains open in webview (not in a web browser).

Comment: @Rose What do you mean " the link can not be opened"? I tested this code with your example project, it works well.